# diiferent DIV with xpath

Tags: html, xpath

i tried to parse a website
but sometimes the page show some ads
and the DIV[x] change

```
DIV[3] when there is no ads 
DIV[4] when the ads comeout
```

there is some
element on the div @data-ssr and @datatest-id
but it didnt works using input[]

```
<div data-testid="divSRPContentProducts" data-ssr="contentProductsSRPSSR">...</div>

Original DIV
//div[@id="zeus-root"]/div[1]/div[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[4)]/DIV/DIV/DIV[contains(@class,"css-12sieg3")]    

what i already tried
    //div[@id="zeus-root"]/div[1]/div[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[data-ssr='contentProductsSRPSSR']/DIV/DIV/DIV[contains(@class,"css-12sieg3")]
    //div[@id="zeus-root"]/div[1]/div[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/input[@data-ssr='contentProductsSRPSSR']/DIV/DIV/DIV[contains(@class,"css-12sieg3")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

this will search for any HTML element that has the `data-ssr`
`//*[@data-ssr='contentProductsSRPSSR']`

if you know that it is a div
`//div[@data-ssr='contentProductsSRPSSR']`

Comment: Just tried it and it worked

Comment: didnt works need need to be inside the DIV?

Comment: what is inside of the div ? What text?

Comment: <div data-testid="divSRPContentProducts" data-ssr="contentProductsSRPSSR">...</div> no text inside the div

Comment: already works with |

//*[@data-testid="divSRPContentProducts" and @data-ssr="contentProductsSRPSSR"]/DIV/DIV/DIV[contains(@class,"css-12sieg3")]

thank you